# integrate spatial and non spatial database oracle

Tags: oracle, spatial

Hye all, i have a problem, my situation is, i have 2 database in difference server, spatial database oracle  and non spatial database oracle,  example below;

spatial database(server 1)= id,code,name,x coordinate, y coordinate
non spatial database (server 2)= no_id, code, street

1) how i want to integrate with gis system, when user makes query for example, insert code=123, than the information appear on map have id,name,code,street, x and y coordinate.

2) how i wan to handle, when user update non spatial database for example, enter new code and at the same time the spatial database have new record also

thank for your help, really need solution

Answer (score 0):

You could join these in a similar way to other database instances, through the use of **Database Links** and **Views**.

If you take this path then I would recommend creating any views by pulling data TO the spatial database, as because SDO_GEOMETRY is treated as a user defined data type there are limitations on it's use across database links where many of the Oracle Locator or Filter functions can not be invoked on a remote instance.

For example on the spatial DB, where the other database is accessible through the 'ops' database link, and the SDO_GEOMETRY column is named shape:

```
select a.id, a.code, a.name, a.x_coordinate, a.y_coordinate, a.shape,
b.code, b.street
from a, b@ops
where a.id = b.id;
```

How you would then interrogate this view combining the street and location information will depend on your GIS application.

Comment: Thanks kes, you have any reference that i can refer?or have any example for this situation

Comment: Hi Wan, I've added a small sql example of a view - for more information on using Oracle spatial I'd recommend the book ['Pro Oracle Spatial'](http://www.apress.com/9781590598993)

Comment: There are no "Spatial Databases or tables" just spacial columns and they co-exist with regular columns just fine.